# Need better information on how to use VS2008 Setup Project to deploy a .NET Win App

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-project

MSDN is a nice place to get vague, general information on this, with just a enough detail to make you wish you had more. The best info on MSDN I found was in the section on Windows Home Server (oddly enough), but it wasn't complete enough to be totally useful.

Is there another source with some DETAIL on how to create an MSI using a VS2008 Setup Project to deploy a Winforms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup projects have remained relatively unchanged between VS versions.  Try these:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx

http://en.csharp-online.net/Deploying_Windows_Applications